# GitHub push and commit with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

I having an issue with Eclipse when I push and commit a project to GitHub.

[image: I can't open "provaspringsecurity" project]

In the *Package Explorer* the code regarding that project disappears so as in the GitHub master repository!

Does that mean I lost my project?

In GitHub the project is there with just a `bin` folder and `.project` file.

Comment: Could you please describe exactly the steps you made (have you already shared it)? Is there something in the _Error Log_ view? Which Eclipse and Java version do you use?

Comment: Eclipse STS 4.1.0 on ubuntu running openjdk11. First in Eclipse I clone my github repository providing the url (ending with .git suffix). Then I select a project in the package explorer and do: Team->Share Project.., in the dialog box I select my .git repository and click finish. Then do Team->Commit and in the Git Staging tab I add all file, write a commit mesage and do Commit and push...I must say the moment I get in the Git Staging tab I see those Bib and .project file instead of the real project.

Comment: The HotSpot or the OpenJ9 OpenJDK 11? If the OpenJ9 with `-Xshareclasses`, you probably run into this issue: https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/4113 Is there something in the _Error Log_ view?

Comment: java -version returns the following: openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode). The error log is clean right now.

Comment: Okay, then it is not related. What is the project location (right-click project folder: _Properties: Resource_) and the location of your workspace (_File > Switch Workspace > Other..._)?

Comment: When I add the project to the local repository (Team->Share Project..) it moves from eclipse default folder to git folder on my home directory. The project is there with .project file and empty bin folder.

Comment: Maybe the project files have not been moved. Are the files still in the workspace?